# USB isn't recognised during UEFI boot mode? (Installing Ubuntu)

Tags: dual-boot

I've decided to install and learn Linux today and decided to try and install Ubuntu, however I've been stuck for a while, and haven't been able to find an answer online. When I'm in the boot mode and trying to change the priority from Windows to Ubuntu on my USB drive, it's not recognized, despite trying multiple things for hours. The answer may be simple but I'm at a loss, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

So I backed up my computer, then installed Ubuntu from - http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

I then created a boot-able Ubuntu USB drive, firstly using Rufus, then secondly using Universal USB Installer on a different USB, as I thought maybe the problem was the USB stick itself.

I also shrunk my drive and left 100 GB of unallocated space, turned off fast boot and also turned off secure boot. I did see a few people mentioning the Legacy option but I've not been able to find that after searching online on where to find it.

This is a screenshot from the boot menu, if it's at all helpful.

[image]

Thanks everyone.

Comment: You show an UEFI entry for UEFI: Kingston Hper... which is your flash drive. You need to use that entry to boot. Some let you choose it easier with the one time boot key like f12, check manual for your system. And some do not allow USB boot unless you specifically allow it in UEFI. Usually not allowed with Secure boot on, but may still need setting even with Secure boot off.

Comment: I was hesitant to use this for the past hour as the USB I'm using is a SanDisk and it still showed when the USB isn't plugged in, and didn't want to risk anything by selecting it. Is it definitely that or?

Comment: I did try and load via the displayed USB drive but nothing happened.

Comment: You need a 64bit OS to boot in UEFI mode. Did you maybe (accidentally) download a 32bit Ubuntu iso?